# Adding values to a JSON object in jquery

Tags: jquery

I am retrieving values from an HTML element from its attributes as follows :

```
  var carDetails = $('.bid-car').map(function () {
            return { "dateCar": $(this).attr('date-car'), "carId": $(this).attr('car-id') };
        });
```

The output is as follows:

```
0: {dateCar: "27/08/2018 22:39:53", carId: "1624"}
```

Now I have a json object defined as follows:

```
var carObj = { dateCar: , carId: }
```

My question is how can I pass this `carObj` to :

```
   $.ajax({
               type: 'POST',
               url: '@Url.Action("CheckCar", "Cars")',
               data:
               {
                   cars: JSON.stringify(carObj )
               },
```

In my controller I have a function which accepts as parameter a `cars` object.

Comment: `JSON` stands for JavaScript Object Notation, which defines how you can make a string represent an array or object in string format.  But it is still a String.  It is not a JSON Object.  And what you have in your `carObj` is not JSON.  It's just an Object.  Edit: though that object is formatted incorrectly as it is missing values for the keys, so that will be a syntax error

Comment: @Taplar How to correct that ?

Comment: Which part?  As far a calling it a JSON Object, don't.  Call it JSON, or an Object, which ever it is.  As far as your syntax error, objects expect `{ key: value, key2: value2 }` syntax, so your `var carObj = { dateCar: , carId: }` example doesn't follow that pattern.

Comment: I want to return in an object of `cars` which can consists of many `dateCar` and `carId` so that I can pass this `cars` to the controller

Comment: Well, your `carDetails` contains a single element matching that pattern, no?  So you want to give the first element of the array to the ajax, right?  How do you reference a specific element in an array?

Comment: I want to pass the whole array to the ajax. If the array contains 10 elements, I want to pass all the 10 elements.

Comment: Ok, then stringify the array and send it.  I'm confused now about what the question is.

Comment: When I am stringifying carDetails, its giving me `Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    at JSON.stringify (<anonymous>)`

Comment: Circular structures are objects which have a child that has a value of a parent elements.  Such as `var parent = {};  var child = { parent: parent }; parent.child = child;`  The parent contains the child that contains the parent that contains the child that .....   Structures like that cannot be converted to JSON.  However, nothing in the question you have shown should result in circular logic.

Comment: Please help me bro. I am totally stuck

Comment: Why not simply `data: {cars: carDetails},` ?

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery `.map()` method doesn't return an array, it returns a jQuery collection. These cannot be stringified because they contain many cross-references between the elements. You can use the `.get()` method to extract an array of the contents.

```
var carDetails = $('.bid-car').map(function () {
    return { "dateCar": $(this).attr('date-car'), "carId": $(this).attr('car-id') };
}).get();
```